# ECS Fargate : Logstash container sharing volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, logstash, aws-fargate

I am running a task in Fargate which have a php-fpm container and nginx container. I've added a third one that runs Logstash and in my conf it listens to php/nginx logs.

When i run it locally, I can see in Kibana my logs, but in Fargate not.
What I did is to add "volumes_from" parameter on the logstash container and added the php and nginx ones. Is it not sufficient ?

I've checked also the permissions in those files and it should be ok.

Below my task definition :

```
"executionRoleArn": "",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/",
          "awslogs-region": "eu-west-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [],
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": "",
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": null,
      "volumesFrom":[],
      "image": "nginx image",
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": false,
      "links": [],
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "nginx"
    },
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/",
          "awslogs-region": "eu-west-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 9000
        }
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [],
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": "",
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": null,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "image": "image php",
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "php"
    },
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/",
          "awslogs-region": "eu-west-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 5400
        },
        {
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 9600
        }
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [],
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": null,
      "volumesFrom": [
        {
          "sourceContainer": "php",
          "readOnly": null
        },
        {
          "sourceContainer": "nginx",
          "readOnly": null
        }
      ],
      "image": "logstash image",
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": false,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "elk"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "4096",
  "taskRoleArn": "arn",
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2",
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn",
  "family": "task-def-fargate",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.17"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    }
  ],
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "cpu": "2048",
  "revision": 51,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "volumes": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved.

I forgot to expose the logs directories in my php and nginx Dockerfiles.